# Running html-embedded php on Apache/Mountain Lion locally

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-mountain-lion

With the Apache and php pre-installed on OS X Mountain Lion, here are the steps I thought sufficient to run a server locally—without installing [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) (which would install duplicates):

1. Uncomment the line `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.
2. Add the [appropriate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58183/7985) `/etc/apache2/users/calaf.conf`.
3. Save the php example above in ~/Sites/introductory-example.html (*correction*)
4. [Restart Apache](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/66361/7985) by running `sudo apachectl start` (or `sudo apachectl restart`).
5. Save a file containing `<html><head><title>Example</title></head><body><php? echo "Hi"; ?></body></html>` (or rather, be precise, [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php) one) twice—first in /Library/WebServer/Documents/introductory-example.html and a duplicate in `~(whoami)/Sites/introductory-example.html`).

I now expect that pointing to either `http://localhost/introductory-example.html` or to `http://localhost/~calaf/introductory-example.html` will give me a page with two features:

1. The title of the page is "Example".
2. The body of the page is "Hi."

Whether I am looking at the `introductory-example.html` in `/Library/WebServer/Documents` or in `~/Sites/` I get the first (the title is correct) but not the second (the body is empty)—why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge PHP is not activated system wide. It isn't in any system and/or combination I ever tried anyways. Apache is running PHP for files in a particular folder only (and its sub-folders). The standard apache folder should be in:

/Library/WebServer/Documents/

[This guide](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion) should get you up and running although I haven't tried it myself.

**EDIT:**

You need to save a file which contain PHP code in .php, **not** .html. Rename or re-save the file to *introductory-example.php*

The following URL do not work since the path does not exist.

```
 http://localhost/Users/calaf/Sites/introductory-example.html
```

Use the following URL (you maybe need to remove the tilde ~)

```
http://localhost/~calaf/introductory-example.php
```

Comment: Re: "Apache is running PHP for files in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ only" Pointing to file://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/introductory-example.html loads the file fine, but php does not run. Also, I am already doing everything related to Apache and php in the guide you point to.

Comment: Your first point (that http://localhost/Users/.. does not exist) is right. But (regarding the second http://..) I can indeed access the file http://localhost/~calaf/introductory-example.html just fine. It's just that the php code embedded in the html file does not run.

Comment: you need to re-save your file to introductory-example.php. Note the extension. HTML files will not execute PHP code.

Comment: Interesting. So my understanding was flawed at a basic level. I had gathered that if I have a file containing <html>..</html> with some php within, the file would still be saved as an html file. If the file had <?php .. ?> and contained within commands echoing some html, it would be a php file (with a php extension). In fact the rule is that the file should have a php extension once it contains some php code, even if the outermost tags are html tags.

Comment: exactly. php files can contain html, php, some xml and css code. HTML files can only contain formatting.(PHP is server side scripting)

Answer (score 1):

I ways symlink /Library/WebServer/Documents into my home folder, and change apache to run as my user instead of the default user. Also you need to enable htaccess for most PHP code (set AllowOverride to "All" I think) and probably install MySQL (the official pkg installation will work out of the box with apple's pre installed PHP).

If you aren't comfortable configuring apache, then MAMP is a good idea.

Comment: Symlinking is just for convenience; is that right? Changing "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" and restarting Apache does not help. How do you "change apache to run as my user instead of the default user"? Is tweaking anything in MySQL necessary even for only a combination of html and php?

Comment: You might not need to change AllowOverride, and you might not need MySQL, they're not related to your problem... I was just predicting you will run into those issues next if you decide to install WordPress or any other common PHP software.

Comment: I think the problem you're having will be solved by what I said in the first sentence of my answer: use /Library/WebServer/Documents instead of ~/Sites. If you want, delete ~/Sites and run `ln -s /Library/WebServer/Documents ~/Sites`. I suspect you have different security settings based on whether you are using /Library or ~/, and that is causing issues.

Comment: Also, if any of this is too hard, then I suggest installing MAMP instead: http://www.mamp.info

Comment: Change the user apache runs as by editing the "User" and "Group" lines in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to something like `User calaf` and `Group calaf` (where calaf is your UNIX username, which is usually the name of your home folder).

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. AllowOverride +1.